# Search and dropdownbox like facebook chat

Tags: jquery, dropdown, html-select

Hello i would like to create a input with text box where everytime a letter matches the letter you got it will create a drop box under the textbox with names that are equal to the text you type in the textbox. Like facebook chat for adding members to a chat. See pic:

Now i know how to make the search work, the only problem , i chose to hide every option and then show it which causes the options to show up like this (see pic 2) If you look at the first pic (Facebooks dropdownbox) you can see that it is attached to the textbox while mine is simply options that show on type. Is there anyway to connect both of these without using a select

[image: This is how i want it]

[image]

My code so far:

```
    $(document).ready(function () 
{
var searchBox = $(".search");

$("option").each(function () 
{
    $(this).hide();
});

searchBox.on('input', function () {
var searchBoxText = $(this).val().toLowerCase();

if(searchBox.length > 0)
{
    $(".person").each(function () 
    {
        var name = $(this).children(".name").text().toLowerCase();

        if(name.indexOf(searchBoxText) != -1)
        {
            $(this).show();
        }
        else 
        {
            $(this).hide();
        }
    });
}
else 
{
    $(".person").each(function () 
{
    $(this).hide();
});

}

});

});
```

Comment: For better understanding i want you to post your code here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is solved now.

I found autocomplete works like a charm.

Anyone that stumbles across this topic and has the same question.

Here is a potentiall solution: https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/